# Permanent redirect of language path (?language=en to /en/)

Tags: apache, drupal, redirect, url-rewriting

I am altering the language specific path on a Drupal setup from a url get parameter (?language=en) to a url prefix /en/. I need to check if the requested url contains the language parameter(?language=en) and then redirect it.

I have 4 languages(da, en, de, pl) that should be redirected using this structure:

```
www.example.com/blog?language=da => www.example.com/blog  (This is the default language)
www.example.com/blog?language=en => www.example.com/en/blog
www.example.com/blog?language=de => www.example.com/de/blog
www.example.com/blog??language=pl => www.example.com/pl/blog
```

Answer (score 2):

Below conditions can be used :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^language=da$
RewriteRule ^/blog /blog/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^language=(en|de|pl)$
RewriteRule ^/blog /%1/blog/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can this be done for all urls containing (?language=en): 

www.example.com/*/?language=en 


www.example.com/?language=en 


www.example.com/?language=de

So its not just for the /blog folder but also works for /about /work etc.

Comment: In order to make it work for /about /work also, you need to replace the rewrite rule as : for da =   RewriteRule ^/(blog|about|work) /$1/? [R=301,L]  .  For en,de and pl =     RewriteRule ^/(blog|about|work) /%1/$1/? [R=301,L]

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} language=en
RewriteRule ^/blog /en/blog/? [R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} language=de
RewriteRule ^/blog /de/blog/? [R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} language=pl
RewriteRule ^/blog /pl/blog/? [R=301]
```

Comment: Can this be done for all urls containing (?language=en):

`www.example.com/*/?language=en`

`www.example.com/?language=en`

`www.example.com/?language=de`

ect..